# Bitly to shorten url java / android

Tags: java, android

I am shortening a url using bitlyj library by following this sample.

To get My api key: i register for a free account on bitlyj official website.

Then i follow this link http://bitly.com/a/your_api_key to get my api key.

Here's my implementation.

```
import com.rosaloves.bitlyj.Url;
import static com.rosaloves.bitlyj.Bitly.*;

Url url = as("bitlyapidemo", 
"MY_API_KEY").call(shorten("http://rosaloves.com/stories/view/13"));
String ul = url.getShortUrl();
System.out.println("art bitfly:"+ url);
```

When i run this sample i got this error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{….. com.rosaloves.bitlyj.BitlyException: INVALID_APIKEY
```

a help please ?

Comment: What else do expect people to say, than the error already does? Something goes wrong with your api key. Request a new one, be sure to give it correctly, good luck.

Comment: apparently your key is invalid ? (duh)

Comment: I hope you didn't post your actual API key there ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in your Runtime Exception: You have an Invalid API Key, that means, your current API Key is not working. You can request a new API Key and try again.

Comment: how to request a new api key?

Comment: under Bitly->Settings->Advanced, look for Legacy API Key, Click on Reset and a new API Key will be presented. Let me know if this works, if not, I can try to code this out for you.

Comment: The api key is still invalid

Comment: I tried this and came up with the same exception, i read through their guide and they didn't meantion anything about how API_KEY should be presented. Base on the example it should be a normal String. I check on their issue page and I think you should also star this issue https://code.google.com/p/bitlyj/issues/detail?id=10

Comment: since it has nothing to do with android here, I just created a java application and test the API from bitly. I personnally think it should work, else why do they provide the API Key at the first place. I'll do some digging on this.

Answer (score 0):

Bitly has deprecated API Key authentication. Please see here: https://dev.bitly.com/authentication.html. You can use now OAuth.